# How do Kill SYSTEM Process?

Tags: process, system, kill, terminate

How do I kill SYSTEM process **via cmd line tools**?

I want to kill **PHotkey.exe** but not work any cmdline tools.

[image: Picture]

I tried apps and not working (access denied error);

```
Taskkill
PsKill
```